# Looping over dict without nested for loops

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, python-itertools

I have a dictionary called params. I need to loop over this dict so that it prints every possible combination of learn_rate and btch_size in order.
Here is my dict:

```
params = dict(
    learn_rate = [0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]
    ,btch_size = [50, 70, 80]

)
```

desired output:

```
0.01 50
0.01 70
0.01 80
0.001 50
0.001 70
0.001 80
0.0001 50
0.0001 70
0.0001 80
```

I was considering using itertools for this as I do not want loads of nested for loops incase I decide to add new lists. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721847/how-to-generate-all-combination-from-values-in-dict-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'itertools.product()' does exactly that. Works with as many lists as you want to add.

```
>>> list(itertools.product(*params.values()))
[(0.01, 50), (0.01, 70), (0.01, 80), (0.001, 50), (0.001, 70), (0.001, 80), (0.0001, 50), (0.0001, 70), (0.0001, 80)]
>>>
```