# How to get a all combinations of two dictionnaries to make a new one in Python

Tags: python

I want to get all combinations on two dictionnaries to get a new one:

```
d1={'a':1.2,'b':1.5,'c':1.3}
d1={'a':2,'b':1,'c':2}
```

into:

```
d={('a','a'):2.4,('a','b'):1.2,('a','c'):2.4,...}
```

where the new keys will be the combinations the initials dicts, ex: `('a','a')` and the new values will be the product of previous values, ex: `1.2 * 2 = 2.4`

Comment: maybe duplication? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721847/how-to-generate-all-combination-from-values-in-dict-of-lists-in-python

Comment: Note that lists cannot be used as dictionary keys, you have to use tuples

Comment: your math doesn't add up.  1.2+1.5 =2.7, not 1.2 (for a,b). can you be more specific about your formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want the product of the values, you can use:

```
d1={'a':1.2,'b':1.5,'c':1.3}
d2={'a':2,'b':1,'c':2}

from itertools import product

out = {k: d1[k[0]]*d2[k[1]] for k in product(d1, d2)}
# or
out = {(k1, k2): d1[k1]*d2[k2] for k1, k2 in product(d1, d2)}
```

Generic answer for an arbitrary number of dictionaries:

```
from itertools import product
from math import prod

dicts = [d1, d2]

out = {k: prod(d[key] for key,d in zip(k,dicts))
       for k in product(*dicts)}
```

Output:

```
{('a', 'a'): 2.4,
 ('a', 'b'): 1.2,
 ('a', 'c'): 2.4,
 ('b', 'a'): 3.0,
 ('b', 'b'): 1.5,
 ('b', 'c'): 3.0,
 ('c', 'a'): 2.6,
 ('c', 'b'): 1.3,
 ('c', 'c'): 2.6}
```

Comment: The intended result is the product, not the sum of the values.

Comment: In the interest of readability, it might be simpler to unpack the pair immediately, and repack it for use as key in the new `dict`. That is, `out = {(k1, k2): d1[k1]*d2[k2] for k1, k2 in product(d1, d2)}`. For that matter, you can take the product of the key/value pairs themselves: `out = {(k1, k2): v1*v2 for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in product(d1.items(), d2.items())}`

Comment: (Though the arbitrary-dict solution is quite readable for even 2 dicts.)

Comment: @chepner I actually hesitated to do this, so I guess you're right ;)

Comment: I won't bike-shed the arbitrary-dict solution :)

Comment: Can you please edit my question so it will be more comprehensible ?